# Windshield wiper arms do not go all the way across the windshield at times

Tags: honda

Honda 2001 accord. Sometimes my windshield wiper arms do not go all the way across the windshield, at other times they do, and again at other times they clack down like they're hitting the bottom of the windshield. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Comment: It sounds as though you need to take a look at the wiper transmission/motor to see if there's slop in any of the pivot points. Any of the bushings could be bad.